# vim latex-suite only working if existing `.tex` file includes latex code

Tags: editors, vim, vim-latex

On a fresh vim latex-suite install, none of the vim latex-suite shortcuts work unless there's pre existing latex code in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to follow step 2 from the 
installation manual :

> The recommended settings for vim-latex in your .vimrc file are now
>   only described in the [vim-latex
>   manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html).

Remember to follow all the steps when installing ;-)